# Convert address[1] to address[]

Tags: solidity, contract-development, solidity-0.8.x

I have a function that takes an array of addresses

```
function _myfunc(address[] memory addresses) public { magic(); }
```

I *cannot* modify this function.

I need to pass `[msg.sender]` to this function, but solc won't let me:

```
Invalid implicit conversion from address[1] memory to address[] memory
```

I'm on solidity 0.8.x

Comment: You could create an array of size 1 and copy the value of msg.sender to the first/only element and then pass this array as argument. You can't convert it directly, because msg.sender is not on the memory, so you need to copy it there.